# Value $A_q (n,n-1) $ code $C \subseteq F_q^n $

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Can you find value $A_q (n,n-1) $ code $C \subseteq F_q^n $ where $A_q(n,n-1)$ is the maximum number of words of length $n$, with minimum Hamming distance $n-1$.

I know if $n> \binom{q+1}{2}$ then $A_q (n,n-1) = q$. Can you give me a general result?!

Comment: Looking at these [table of known bounds for $A_q(n,d)$](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/), (see the links in the Coding Theory section), it appears $A_q(\binom{q+1}2,\binom{q+1}2-1)=q+1$ for $q\ge 3$. I think a constructive proof of this would be a good start.